# whats up with passing proxy information in Gradle?

Tags: http, proxy, installation, gradle, proxy-server

in gradle, how can I setup that I can pass to my proxy server demanding information such as in ANT
    -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyhost
    -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
    -Dhttp.proxyUser=C770
    -Dhttp.proxyPassword=gagapwd
    -Dhttp.auth.preference=Basic

defining that for ANT and MAVEN and JSVN works, tested today.
doing so for gradel does not at all.

does gradle somehow handle this by itself? if yes, then where can I find a little little reference to just a word "proxy" in the source code of gradle? I couldnt find any such words. can someone please explain?

I was directed onnce in a e-mail by a gralde crack or the like to setup under gradle.properties the following
    systemProp.http.proxyHost=myproxyserver.com
    systemProp.http.proxyport=8080
    systemProp.http.proxyUser=C770
    systemProp.http.proxyPassword=orbxorbx
    systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
    systemProp.http.auth.preference=Basic

both setups have absolute no effect - I check it with a WireShark - and guess I know why: because some times in the past I have svn checked out as usually my svnkit; then on a bad day, the maven pom and the ant build where gone; to be replaced with something better. gradle. Since the gradle.bat, how ever you trim it, does not work behind my proxyserver, does not pass any of the informations given as said above to the wire, I feel very sad for gardle. It is not what I need to start beleaving about gradle. Also - I tried to download lates gradle kits. the -all and -bin kit versions are delivering my zip archives whith unexpected end of file; result ; unable to unzip it. while the gradle-src kit comes down real smart. What is up with gradle today?

Josef - very sad about that MVN and ANT have been taken out from svnkit project to be replaced by something which does not work after doing an svn update to an existing long lasting project.

Comment: With which gradle version was the wrapper generated? I think this issue was fixed with 1.0-milestone-8. Can you try to rerun the wrapper task with a newer gradle version?

Answer (score 5):

I got this to work by setting the appropriate options in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. Assuming your in windows entering something like this in the command prompt should do the trick.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

yes - same problem using gradle with proxy.

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/proxy_error-1r4f6

Comment: tl;dr (it's a long ticket) "a bug in [HttpClient](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1107) and will be fixed in 4.2.3" but that ticket is only for NTLM, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Currently is working for me following the next steps:

1. Ensure you haven't duplicity between your file $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties and $YOUR_GRADLE_PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER/gradle.properties. In that case only keep one of them and remove the other, you choose which file.
2. Configure your http and https proxy in gradle.properties in following way

-

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your proxy host, ie: 123.456.789.10
systemProp.http.proxyPort=your proxy port, ie: 8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|other.host.to.ignore
systemProp.http.keepAlive=true

systemProp.https.proxyHost=your proxy host, ie: 123.456.789.10
systemProp.https.proxyPort=your proxy port, ie: 8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost|other.host.to.ignore
systemProp.https.keepAlive=true
```

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: and I have found a very nice program/service helping you to login to proxy servers; it's cntlm Cntlm Authentication Proxy, it helps you login using username password and domain and can do NTLM-v2 login protocol/schema. Josef

Comment: to the point 2. configure your https ... where do I say which schema to use. BASIC, DIGEST, NTLM, NEGOTIATE ? this as a HINT to the proxy-sever given it suports hints. And how do I give the DOMAIN-NAME given the proxy does only allow NTLM type logins???? 

That is exactly the case at our company, and that made me seek for a tool like Cntlm which works perfect and is able to log you in at the corporate firewall/proxyserver. And. the application, in my case maven, does not care to deal with my local Cntlm proxy server as long as it get's what it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I got lots of warnings from maven, which was unable to pass through our corporate proxy server demanding NTLM-v2 to login.

Since I am using Cntlm as a first proxy server on my lab-top, and give him username, password and the domainname, and then start it as a service; then redirect maven via service.xlm to talk to Cntlm as proxy-serever at a different port, and have it forward all to the corporate proxy, since then Cntlm manages the login and as a client toward the real proxy, maven does not care to talk to Cntlm as proxy as long as all goes through the first and the second proxy and retuns promtly from maven-central.

Maybe you should try Cntlm with gradel, and if it does not work tell me.